# Fulfillment Webhook in Python for Dialogflow

Tags: python, flask, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I want to develop a webhook in Python using Flask. All documentation and tutorials I found online are for Node.js.

How can I include suggestion chips and action cards for some intents, using Python in a webhook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [Responses doc](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/responses) for Actions on Google, you can see the JSON responses that you can use rather than Node.js.

A response with a suggestion chip has this format:

```
{
  "payload": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "richResponse": {
        "items": [
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "These are suggestion chips."
            }
          },
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "Which type of response would you like to see next?"
            }
          }
        ],
        "suggestions": [
          {
            "title": "Suggestion 1"
          },
          {
            "title": "Suggestion 2"
          },
          {
            "title": "Suggestion 3"
          }
        ],
        "linkOutSuggestion": {
          "destinationName": "Suggestion Link",
          "url": "https://assistant.google.com/"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively you can find a pre-existing library from a third-party developer to provide fulfillment, such as [flask-dialogflow](https://github.com/ONSEIGmbH/flask-dialogflow).